# setSupportActionBar() always raises NullPointerException

Tags: android, toolbar

I tried to switch from ActionBar to Toolbars because I wanted to apply the new Material design.

Unfortunateley my approach did't work out and `setSupportActionBar()` always raises a NullPointerException.

The appcompat library is included as a library project and the dependency in the project settings are also set.

Any suggestions?

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myApp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".view.screens.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
         </activity>
     </application>
</manifest>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ktbl_red</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ktbl_green</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/ktbl_yellow</item>

        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    </style>
```

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/ktbl_blue"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge>
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
</merge>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);;

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar); // error (NPE)
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

NullPointerExecption

```
02-23 14:21:38.564    3687-3687/com.example.myApp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myApp/com.example.myApp.view.screens.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:95)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:88)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.<init>(ToolbarActionBar.java:84)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setSupportActionBar(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:175)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setSupportActionBar(ActionBarActivity.java:92)
            at de.ktbl.com.example.myApp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: In `activity_main.xml` you should not use `<merge>` tag. Place there LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.

Comment: What is line 33 in `MainActivity`?

Comment: @Blackbelt yes it's null. I checked it with an if statement.

Comment: @Josef It's `setSupportActionbar(toolbar);`

Comment: Try putting `toolbar` in your `activity_main.xml`

Comment: @Josef I tried it... same problem :(

Comment: Remove this line : 
       `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>`

Comment: @Josef I removed it... the NPE still raises

Comment: "I tried to switch from ActionBar to Toolbars since it's usage is stated as deprecated" -- the action bar is not deprecated.

Comment: My fault... I meant the `ActionBar.TabListener`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29393169/setsupportactionbar-throws-nullpointer-exception/32371016#32371016

Comment: [Here is the answer given briefly][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29393169/setsupportactionbar-throws-nullpointer-exception/32371016#32371016

Comment: @Kody, do you still have this problem? I am getting hit by this and none of the solutions in SO seem to be working for me. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: @KevinGhaboosi Yes, I was still facing that problem. I decided to switch back to the 'old' solution, since I didn't get that running :(

Comment: @Kody, I just fixed it today. I'm using `Butterknife` to inject the toolbar along with other views I need to work on. Moreover, I am now using `v4.AppCompat` rather than `ActionBarActivity`. Although I am using lots of dagger stuff, I can share some snippets here for the sake of trying if you are still interested in giving it a final try. Let me know.

Comment: @KevinGhaboosi Sure :) I would appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this hopefully it will remove the NPE ...

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); // or getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

Hope it helps .... :)

Comment: I declared this above the `Toolbar` part and now I get a NPE for `actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);` (I've imported the support actionbar)

Comment: ok try giving the action bar a title or assign logo like that 
actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.abc);
        actionBar.setTitle(getTitle());*/

Answer (score 0):

Its happen when object is unknown or is null. This can happen when you forgot to set object, the source library is unknown (cannot be found) or you use wrong use type.

On which device did you tested that app? lower than API 15?
Try to check library support

I think that you have used code on wrong way.

-1) FIX your manifest file (you forgot end mark of activity)

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".view.screens.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
         </activity>
</application>
```

your java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar); // error (NPE)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //set view at end
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I used a API15 device/emulator. The support library seems to be included correctly, I could build the project and the support classes/xml elements are also known.  `</activity>` is in the Manifest. It got lost when I prepared the code for here.. (Didn't want to post the complete Manifest with ~ 100 lines. I'll fix it in the question.

Comment: In google i saw that examle: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html. Try to enter that code in your main activity <merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

Comment: Btw... setting the content view after setting up the toolbar is not correct --> https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/